# New Flutter app has same font style as one of my previous apps

Tags: android, flutter, fonts, styles

I created a new Flutter app from scratch, in Android Studio. In one of my previous apps, I intentionally used a weird font style. Now, for some reason, the new app has the same fonts. Is it possible that I had stored some "global" font style somewhere in the Android Studio, and now it's getting re-used? How can I get rid of it and revert the "normal" fonts?

Here's the code of one widget and its screenshot in the emulator:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Login'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
              },
            ),
            Text('Login'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, there shouldn't be.

In my case it also appeared in the debug app, but disappeared again when I recompiled the project. I haven't seen it in a finished app yet.